# list files with different extensions from a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to list specific file extensions in a directory in one go? e.g; I just want to list all `.jpg` and `.gif` files from a directory.
This is how I do for only `jpeg` files:

```
@images = Dir.glob("my/pictures/*.jpg")
```

how to do this for both `jpg`(s) and `gif`(s)? tnx.

Comment: a very simple Google research: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do as below

```
@images = Dir.glob("my/pictures/*.{jpg,gif}")
```

From documentation of [`{p,q}`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob)

> Matches either literal `p` or literal `q`. Equivalent to pattern alternation in *regexp*. Matching literals *may be more than one character in length*. More than two literals may be specified.

Comment: You have left an extra space between `gif` and `}`.